# How to input a specific three-variable function into this definition?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, vector-calculus

I have the following expression:

```
    S5[f_, \[Psi]_] := D[f, {x, 0}, {y, 4}] + 2*D[f, {x, 2}, {y, 2}] + D[f, {x, 4}, {y, 0}] + 
   \[Mu]^2*(\[Mu]^2*f*Derivative[0, 1, 0][\[Psi]][x, y, t]^4 + 12*D[f, {x, 0}, {y, 1}]*
      Derivative[0, 1, 0][\[Psi]][x, y, t]*Derivative[0, 2, 0][\[Psi]][x, y, t] + 
     3*f*Derivative[0, 2, 0][\[Psi]][x, y, t]^2 + 4*f*Derivative[0, 1, 0][\[Psi]][x, y, t]*
      Derivative[0, 3, 0][\[Psi]][x, y, t] + 8*D[f, {x, 1}, {y, 1}]*
      Derivative[0, 1, 0][\[Psi]][x, y, t]*Derivative[1, 0, 0][\[Psi]][x, y, t] + 
     4*D[f, {x, 1}, {y, 0}]*Derivative[0, 2, 0][\[Psi]][x, y, t]*
      Derivative[1, 0, 0][\[Psi]][x, y, t] + 2*\[Mu]^2*f*Derivative[0, 1, 0][\[Psi]][x, y, t]^2*
      Derivative[1, 0, 0][\[Psi]][x, y, t]^2 + \[Mu]^2*f*Derivative[1, 0, 0][\[Psi]][x, y, t]^4 + 
     2*D[f, {x, 0}, {y, 2}]*(3*Derivative[0, 1, 0][\[Psi]][x, y, t]^2 + 
       Derivative[1, 0, 0][\[Psi]][x, y, t]^2) + 2*D[f, {x, 2}, {y, 0}]*
      (Derivative[0, 1, 0][\[Psi]][x, y, t]^2 + 3*Derivative[1, 0, 0][\[Psi]][x, y, t]^2))
```

S5 is a function of $f$ and $\psi$. I would like to plug in an explicit function $\psi$ and obtain the simplified answer. However, if I input, say `S5[f[x,y,t], x]`, I get

```
Derivative[0, 4, 0][f][x, y, t] + 
  \[Mu]^2*(\[Mu]^2*f[x, y, t]*Derivative[0, 1, 0][x][x, y, t]^4 + 
    12*Derivative[0, 1, 0][f][x, y, t]*Derivative[0, 1, 0][x][x, y, t]*
     Derivative[0, 2, 0][x][x, y, t] + 3*f[x, y, t]*Derivative[0, 2, 0][x][x, y, t]^2 + 
    4*f[x, y, t]*Derivative[0, 1, 0][x][x, y, t]*Derivative[0, 3, 0][x][x, y, t] + 
    4*Derivative[0, 2, 0][x][x, y, t]*Derivative[1, 0, 0][f][x, y, t]*
     Derivative[1, 0, 0][x][x, y, t] + 2*\[Mu]^2*f[x, y, t]*
     Derivative[0, 1, 0][x][x, y, t]^2*Derivative[1, 0, 0][x][x, y, t]^2 + 
    \[Mu]^2*f[x, y, t]*Derivative[1, 0, 0][x][x, y, t]^4 + 
    2*Derivative[0, 2, 0][f][x, y, t]*(3*Derivative[0, 1, 0][x][x, y, t]^2 + 
      Derivative[1, 0, 0][x][x, y, t]^2) + 8*Derivative[0, 1, 0][x][x, y, t]*
     Derivative[1, 0, 0][x][x, y, t]*Derivative[1, 1, 0][f][x, y, t] + 
    2*(Derivative[0, 1, 0][x][x, y, t]^2 + 3*Derivative[1, 0, 0][x][x, y, t]^2)*
     Derivative[2, 0, 0][f][x, y, t]) + 2*Derivative[2, 2, 0][f][x, y, t] + 
  Derivative[4, 0, 0][f][x, y, t],
```

which is of course not what I want. The issue is that instead of actually differentiating $\psi=x$, the output writes for example `Derivative[0, 1, 0][x][x, y, t]^2` instead of $0$( since $\partial_y x=0$). It seems the program is not interpreting the input $x$ as a function that can be differentiated and simplified. Any help is very appreciated. Also, sorry for the messy formatting, this is my first time posting here so I'm not sure how to best write everything up.

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say that the output "is not what you want"? What do you want instead? Can you try to come up with a definition for something like `S5` that still reproduces your problem, but is much simpler?

Comment: Does the edit help?

Comment: Try using `S5[f[x, y, t], # &]`

Comment: Can you expand more on what that command does/means? And what if I want to plus in something like $\psi(x,y)=x+y$?

Comment: Would that look like S5[f[x, y, t], (#1)+(#2) &]?

Comment: You've got it—`# &` is just the identity function, and you're correct that $\psi(x,y) = x + y$ may be given by `#1 + #2 &`. Another way of writing functions is with `|->` (which looks like $\mapsto$ in a notebook), and might be more intuitive: for example, `({x, y} |-> x + y)` or (in the first case) `x |-> x`.